# Smooth Div Scroll is not initializing (or only partial init) on all versions of IE. All other browsers are fine

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a project that implements the [Smooth Div Scroll plugin](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/).

With all other browsers, my code allows the user to scroll horizontally through a bunch of divs, but IE apparently has other ideas. It sporadically chooses to either properly initialize, or only initialize portions of the functionality, or usually just does nothing useful at all.

Relevant jQuery code (and touch of PHP):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("div#sbir-sttr-tool").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling            : true,
    manualContinuousScrolling      : false,
    hotSpotScrollingStep           : 5,
    hotSpotScrollingInterval       : 7,
    easingAfterHotSpotScrolling    : false
    <?php 
      if(isset($_GET['col'])){
        echo ', startAtElementId   : "sbir_' . $_GET['col'] . '"'.PHP_EOL;
      }
    ?>
  });
});
```

The PHP segment is outputting as intended. And like I said, the initialization works flawlessly in other browsers (tested: FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera).

There are no JS errors being thrown in the console. I'm getting a number of 304 loads in IE, but I'm assuming that's not a concern (correct me if I'm wrong).

The issue can be tested here: http://startech1.org/dev/sbir/?col= (where `0 <= col < 5`, or just don't include `col` parameter).

In the event that the issue is some kind of clash with other plugins installed on the page, [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) is also installed and I'm running `jQuery v1.8.0` and `jQuery-UI v1.8.18`.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with IE and SmoothDivScroll.  ANd I'm also using Fancybox on the same site.  Mine wont initialize on IE9 and just gets stuck.  I've tried altering the jQuery versions with IE conditionals to no avail.  Any luck yet?